# Как передать переменную на страницу jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Такой вопрос, передаю переменную на страницу выбора режима просмотра БД таким образом: `<li><a href="modeTmpSelect.jsp?pages=${pages}">Технологічні маршрути споживання об'єктів</a></li>`, при переходе на страницу в адресной строке видно что переменная передалась http://localhost:8080/ViewDb/modeTmpSelect.jsp?pages=15, но когда нажимаю на одну из кнопок, куда я так же указываю этот пераметр, переменная уже теряется, почему это происходит?

```
<a href="SearchTmpCh?page=1&count=0&osdch=${osdch}&osdk=${osdk}&cp=${cp}&svi=<%=svi%>&pages=${pages}" style="padding-right: 10px;">
                <button id="leftBtn" class="left">Режим - Застосовність об'єкту</button></a>
```

в сервлете делаю так

```
 Integer pages;
            try {
                pages = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pages"));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                pages = 25;
            }

request.setAttribute("pages", pages);
```